# create array out of properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a scheduler based on an initial date, an interval and a number of entries, id like to send this up as an array. Ive successfully made all the integer factors that would define the array, and maybe some kind of while loop is appropriate, but if anyone wants to help me work through this, id appreciate it.

```
const it = parseInt(iteration.installments);

let int;

if (iteration.interval === "single") {
  int = 0;
} else if (iteration.interval === "weekly") {
  int = 7;
} else if (iteration.interval === "biweekly") {
  int = 14;
} else if (iteration.interval === "monthly") {
  int = 30;
}

const startDate = new Date(scheduleItem.thirdPaymentDate);
```

so from start date i want to create (it) entries (int) days apart from startdate and produce an array.  Sadly all the existing questions of this nature imply an end date, obviously its some kind of loop, but what?

Comment: "Monthly" is not "every 30 days"...

Comment: Can we assume 1 day = 24 hours?

Comment: sure i dont really care how the math gets done cause its going to create updateable items in an array in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```js
const startDate = Date.now(),
  it = 12,
  int = 7 * 86400000, // int is in millisseconds
  arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < it; i++)
  arr[i] = new Date(startDate + i * int);

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: i had to pass date.parse on my request object to get this to work but it did!